# Android Things 5.1 - 9 bit UART

Tags: android-ndk, uart, android-things, brillo

I'm trying to support 9-bit UART using Android Things,
When I try to set the data size to 9 I receive IO exception.
The only configurations that works are 7 and 8 bits.

I know that is possible to make 9-bit emulation using the parity error interrupt, but on android things, I don't receive any handler of it.

I tried also to set it using the native library, same exception.

Is there a chance to have this interrupt?

I'm using Pico-Pi iMX7D.

I don't understand why there is no high-level support of it.

Thank you in advance

**Moved to feature request here:** https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/67995082

Comment: [Official Documentation](https://developer.android.com/things/sdk/pio/uart.html) claims that the `UART` supports from 5 to 9 data bits. Seems that is bug.

Comment: @AlessioDiMaria this may be a bug in Android Things, so you should use the link above to mention your details and file it as an platform-level bug so it can be triaged by the engineering team.

Comment: @Alessio 
Did you file a bug for this on the [Android Things issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=192720&template=847005)? Might be a platform bug. I assume you're using DP5.1?