# How can I send more than 8 byte data over UART on android Things raspberry pie?

Tags: android, iot, uart, android-things, android-things-console

I want to send more than 8 byte data over the UART connection I am currently using USB 2.0 to TTL with 4 pin. I think my option is to use USB 2.0 to TTL with 6 pins is it correct?
If not what are my option?
for e.g I want to send 234212441325454543595674859764
how can i send it usb to TTL with 4 pins?

Comment: If you really need 9-bit UART, please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46803849/6950238) question. But if you want to send 234212441325454543595674859764 in ASCII - that is normal case for UART. Take a look at [this](https://developer.android.com/things/sdk/pio/uart.html) and [that](https://github.com/androidthings/sample-uartloopback) and many [other](http://nilhcem.com/android-things/discovering-the-UART-api) other examples and tutorials.

Comment: I am able to send data but, I am having string which shown in the example above when i send the string from computer to raspberry pi it came in two subsequent parts. Like 2342124413254545 and then 43595674859764 but i want it in on shot like 234212441325454543595674859764.

Comment: Just concat in.

Comment: already did it...thanks....post answer will mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need 9-bit UART, please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46803849/6950238) question. But if you want to send 234212441325454543595674859764 in ASCII - that is normal case for UART. Take a look at [this](https://developer.android.com/things/sdk/pio/uart.html) and [that](https://github.com/androidthings/sample-uartloopback) and many other examples and tutorials. If you receive not full string, but it parts - just concat them.